# Variational Auto-encoders vs Restricted Boltzmann Machines

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, unsupervised-learning, autoencoders, restricted-boltzmann-machine

What are the differences of modeling ability between Variational Auto-encoders (VAEs) and Restricted Boltzmann Machines (RBMs)?

What I am interested in is to know about the unsupervised learning power differences.
Where exactly VAEs work better than RBMs and vise versa?
Also what RBMs can capture that VAEs can not?

I am already aware of [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/114385/what-is-the-difference-between-convolutional-neural-networks-restricted-boltzma) post and I know the concept of VAEs and RBMs. Also [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94483/are-restricted-boltzmann-machines-better-than-stacked-auto-encoders-and-why?rq=1) one is very brief and is not what I am looking for.

Does anybody know about any (theoretical) limitations on the modeling power for one that makes another superior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Theoretically RBMs are undirected models with no connections between any observed variables or any latent variables, VAEs are directed models with continuous latent variables.

The [Deep Learning](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/) book (Chapter 20 Deep Generative Models) provides a very good summary of pros and cons of VAEs and all types of RBMs.

To quote some

> The VAE framework is very straightforward to extend to a wide range of model architectures. This is a key advantage over Boltzmann machines, which require extremely careful model design to maintain tractability.

> The variational autoencoderis deﬁned for arbitrary computational graphs, which makes it applicable to a wider range of probabilistic model families because there is no need to restrict the choice of models to those with tractable mean ﬁeld ﬁxed point equations.

> One very nice property of the variational autoencoder is that
>   simultaneously training a parametric encoder in combination with the
>   generator network forces the model to learn a predictable coordinate
>   system that the encoder can capture. This makes it an excellent
>   manifold learning algorithm.